# How to dispatch the result of load_pem_public_key?

Tags: python, cryptography

Python's `cyrptography` library offers a convenient `load_pem_public_key` function that can load different kinds of PEM public keys — at the very least EC and RSA public keys.

What's the canonical way to interrogate the return value of this function to determine what kind of public key was loaded?

Printing the return value shows:

- `<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.ec._EllipticCurvePublicKey object at 0x...>`
- `<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x...>`
- (possibly other kinds of keys)

However, different keys have different expectations, for example `key.public_numbers().curve.name` makes sense for an EC public key but not an RSA public key.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `isinstance()` function, for example:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPublicKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import EllipticPublicKey

key = load_pem_public_key(data)
if isinstance(key, RSAPublicKey):
    print("It's an RSA key!")
elif isinstance(key, EllipticCurvePublicKey:
    print("It's and EllipticCurve key!")
else:
    print("It's something else.")
```

This is untested. Remember to also catch the possible `ValueError` from `load_pem_public_key`.

Comment: That's all right, but  importing `_Foo` seems like a bad practice. Likewise importing from `backend` is a little odd when `default_backend` is used.

Comment: True. You can actually see the return types of the functions here: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_public_key
They differ a bit from you example prints, but look like the intended usage. For example `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey`. I modified the answer to correspond.

Comment: `asymmetric.xx.XxxKey` are ABCs (that is concrete classes don't list them as bases). The only difference between the two is that RSA has `.encyrpt` and EC has `.curve`. I feel that this difference being so small, it's an extreme case of  duck-typing  to depend on it, considering there's a total of 8 different `XxxPublicKey` classes "declared" in asymmetric 